when i run npx package show window popup (how do you want to open this app)
i make some cli command base applicatoin and checked found ok and bublish on npm. when i run npx package show window popup (how do you want to open this app)
i have already checked my package.json file and tcscofig file .

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
